WPF - Binding не является допустимым условием триггера
Есть две кнопки, назад и вперёд, которые взаимодействуют с массивом и изменяют индекс элемента, который надо достать из массива.
Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы кнопка назад была недоступна, если выбран первый элемент массива, а кнопка вперед была недоступна, если выбран последний элемент массива. Сначала хотел сделать два свойства (IsFirstElement, IsLastElement), сделать для кнопок триггеры и в коде уже проверять на первый и последний элемент, а затем менять значение свойств.
Потом подумал, что можно просто сравнивать выбранный элемент с единицей (в случае кнопки назад) и с количеством элементов в массиве (в случае кнопки вперёд). Вот реализация кнопки назад:
<Button Content="Назад">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PhotoIndex}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>

Вот реализация кнопки вперед:
<Button Content="Вперед">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PhotoIndex}" Value="{Binding PhotoCount}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>

При биндинге PhotoCount к Value выдает ошибку из шапки темы. Подскажите, можно ли как-то без дополнительных свойств реализовать мою задумку? Возможно необходимо использовать другие триггеры или какие-то дополнительные свойства? Заранее извиняюсь, если такой вопрос уже был, но ответа я не нашёл.

Если Ваш массив выступает источником данных для какого-то элемента управления типа ListView или DataGrid в качестве ItemsSource- я бы воспользовался свойством SelectedItem и создал еще 2 свойства IsFirstElement, IsLastElement, ну или EnableForvardShift, EnableBackShift, которые обновлял бы в SelectedItem.Set() . Это простой и понятный путь. Можно потратить очень много времени на поиск и реализацию элегантного решения (ну, или того, к которому душа лежит) и не получить никакой выгоды, кроме, может быть, морального удовлетворения.

@AlexanderSt этот самый массив - это массив с путями до фотографий, он привязывается к Image и с помощью кнопок листается вперед и назад. Понимаю как решить мою задачу с помощью свойств, просто было интересно, можно ли обойтись без них? Думаю, что делать для кнопки "вперед" свойство, а для кнопки "назад" просто проверять не равен ли индекс единице в самом триггере - не лучшая идея, лучше уж завести два свойства)

А зачем вы вообще это привязываете? У вас должна быть команда, к которой должна быть привязана кнопка. У самой команды должно быть задано CanExecute с нужным значением, вот как бы и все... Сам WPF дальше за вас будет IsEnabled устанавливать.

@EvgeniyZ Да, совершенно про это забыл! Спасибо, давно не прогал на WPF, добавил ответ на свой вопрос, можете посмотреть, все ли правильно я сделал?

Реализовал не через триггеры, а по совету @EvgeniyZ через команды. Реализация выглядит так:
private RelayCommand nextPhotoCommand;
public RelayCommand NextPhotoCommand
{
    get
    {
        return nextPhotoCommand ??
             (nextPhotoCommand = new RelayCommand(x => {CurrentPhoto = Photos[++PhotoIndex];}, 
obj => {return (PhotoIndex != PhotoCount);}));
    }
 }

С помощью этого кода определяется возможность исполнения команды (CanExecute):
obj => {return (PhotoIndex != PhotoCount);}


Все так. Только громоздко как по мне. Можно ведь просто сделать команду public ICommand PreviousPhotoCommand { get; } и в конструкторе прописать PreviousPhotoCommand = new RelayComman(...);, будет куда чище. Ну и да, MessageBox в MVVM является нарушением, ибо окна - это View слой, а вы вызываете View в VM, что как бы, запрещено напрямую. Но это так, на будущее, пища для размышления....

Версия дотнета какая? Если свежая, я бы код помог укоротить.

@EvgeniyZ ну MessageBox технически это WinAPI ) как например реестр. Он же не является компонентом WPF. Так что считать его таким уж View я бы не стал. Но да, такие штуки лучше абстрагировать в отдельные сервис-классы.

@EvgeniyZ знаю про MessageBox, просто вчера не успел написать реализацию команды) Исправил ответ, теперь вроде всё ок
